# Printing first 20 number of fibonacci using R

Tags: r

I am new in R. I make little tasks to learn the R. My english skills is not enough ı know. :)

Now, ı want to print **first 20 number of fibonacci series**. How can ı make this task?
Sorry. But ı cant telling the proplem. I wanna use while condition.

Thank you,
Best regards.

Comment: n=30
f=1:n
f[1]=0
f[2]=1
i=3

while(i<=n) {
f[i]=f[i-1]+f[i-2]
i=i+1
}

print(f)

This is another way !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this :

```
length_fib = 20
fibonacci = numeric(length_fib)
fibonacci[1] = 1
fibonacci[2] = 1
for (i in 3:length_fib) { 
  fibonacci[i] = fibonacci[i-1] + fibonacci[i-2]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, J. This platform is doctor. I am feeling happy :) But how can we make using with while condition.
:)

Comment: What do you mean by using while condition ? If you want n first numbers, just adjust "length_fib".

Comment: I see. I mixed with python. Such  this code,
a,b= 0, 1
while a<22:
 print(a)
 a,b=b,a+b 
Thank you for attention. 

İMÜ'ye selam olsun :)